# Why do most drugs target G-protein receptors?

Tags: medications

[I've read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_target#Drug_targets) that more than 50% drugs target the g-protein coupled receptors: What is so special with them that they are the targets for such a wide range of diseases?

Comment: Where did you read this? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research so linking to the source of this claim would be good.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_target#Drug_targets

Comment: Thank you. I edited your question to add the link. When you're asked for more information, please edit your question and add it rather than just answering in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: The fact you are referring to is not a because of some particular reason desired result - it's just a statistical observation, therefore it is not easy to simply tell "why". G-protein receptors are very common and present a huge variety of specific morphological details, which generally makes them a good instrument to manipulate with drugs. I am not sure if i could add this as an answer though since it lacks a particular information source.

Comment: @practiZ Can you add a citation supporting the basic premise of your answer? That's all that's required.